# Counting rows with data

Tags: excel, vba

Row count works with 2 or more populated rows. If only a single row is populated, it counts the max excel rows instead. How can I handle a single row counter?

Counting populated rows in an excel form for a copy/paste that creates a csv file for upload to another system.

The code works great as long as there is two or more rows with populated data.
However, if it counts a single row, it counts all the way to the bottom 120400 or whatever the max excel row is. (Besides the point). Now 99 times out of 100 this will be fine, but there is the off chance the end user will try and do a single line entry.

`rCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TimeCard").Range("E7", ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TimeCard").Range("E7").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count`

Above scenario has the worksheet of Time card with 6 rows of headers and information. Thus, the first entry line is 7. I have formulas in column E so there is always data in column E, hence why I am using column E to count. If the user only fills in 2 or more rows, the code above functions properly. How can I handle the single line entry?

Adding to this to give more clarity.

So the Worksheet is a time entry worksheet. There is 5 rows of branding and instructional information and what not.

6th row is actual headings for the information the employees will be entering.

Row 7 has a bunch of data validation lists that the employee chooses from, that is the information that will be sent to payroll IE. date, firstname, lastname, the class that they taught, the duration of the class etc.

I have a macro created that inserts another row for the next class as the manager wants to capture time per class.

So most of the  employees teach upwards of 8 classes a day. Thus there will be 8 "time entry" lines. 
However, if they only teach one class there could be just the single line. Immediately following time entry line (as per direction from the requesting manager) they want the a row that has a little disclaimer about submitting there time ticket before 4:00 PM etc..

So to answer some of the comments in regards to counting xlUp, I cannot for sure say that the starting row would always be a certain row.

I hope this helps clarify

Comment: I've always started at the bottom and used xlUp. Of course this assumes that there are no gaps in your data.

Comment: unfortunately I have to have footer information, so I would have to specify a starting row, so I would assume I would run into the same issue counting up? Or not so?

Comment: Where is the footer in relation to the last row of data? If it is always, say, 5 rows below, then you can factor that in.

Comment: What can cause the starting row to shift? You say row 6 is headings, row 7 is start of data entry. I don't see anything in your narrative that would move row 7. Also, which column has the footer/disclaimer? If the text is in column A, it does not interfere with column E, so my answer below will be workable. If not, please help me understand what prevents it from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it counts all the way to the bottom for a single row of entries, then the footer does not lie in its path, otherwise it would reference the first row of the footer. Hence, you can use the following statement, which will return the row number of the last entry in column E and then subtracts 6 to account for the fact that the first entry is in row 7

```
rCount = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("TimeCard").Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row - 6
```

Comment: I tried this, but yours is slightly different than what i had, so I will try this and report back.